# Spark Structured Streaming Deduplication with Watermark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I would like to use Spark Structured Streaming for an ETL job where each event is of form:

```json
{
   "signature": "uuid",
   "timestamp: "2020-01-01 00:00:00",
   "payload": {...}
}
```

The events can arrive late up to 30 days and can include duplicates. I would like to deduplicate them based on the "signature" field.

If I use the recommended solution:

```
streamingDf \
  .withWatermark("timestamp", "30 days") \
  .dropDuplicates("signature", "timestamp")
  .write
```

would that track (keep in memory, store etc) a buffer of the full event content (which can be  quite large) or will it just track the "signature" field values ?

Also, would the simple query like the above write new events immediately as new data arrives or would it "block" for 30 days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "would that track (keep in memory, store etc) a buffer of the full event content (which can be quite large) or will it just track the "signature" field values ?"

Yes, it will keep all columns of `streamingDf` and not only the signature and timestamp columns.

> "Also, would the simple query like the above write new events immediately as new data arrives or would it "block" for 30 days?"

This query will write events immediately as new data arrives and only keep the state at least for 30 days in order to be able to identify duplicates.

---

From my personal experience with streaming applications, I really do **not** recommend your approach for de-duplicating messages. Keeping the state for up to 30 days is quite challenging from an operational point of view. Remember, that any small network glitch, power outage, planned/unplanned maintenance of your OS etc. could cause your application to fail or produce wrong results.

I highly recommend to de-duplicate your data through another approach, like e.g. writing the data into a Delta Table or any other format or database.

Comment: I do intend to write it to a Delta table, however that doesn't seem to help much with deduplication unless I do it on my own as an extra step right ? i.e. read - deduplicate - write back or with a MERGE ON.

Comment: yes, exactly. You need a dedicated logic that deduplicates the data when reading it from that delta table.

Comment: Hi @unvadim, please check my corrected answer. Apologies for the confusion, but I had now the time to play around with the code snippet. And the data arrives immediately irrespective of the 30 days watermark you are using. The watermark only makes sure that duplicates can be identified *at least* for 30 days as Spark will keep the state for that amount of time.

Comment: Thanks @Michael... that is good to know. what about the state kept - do you still think it will be all columns or just those required for deduplication ?

Comment: I recently tested it and it will keep all columns that you select, not only those required for depuplication.